# Isomorphism between $L^p$ space

Tags: functional-analysis

I get a linear map $T:L^p(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^p(\mathbb{R})$ which is continuous for every $p>1$ (the constant depends on $p$), and an isomorphism for $p=2$.

Is that an isomorphism for every $p>1$?

Thx in advance

Comment: What is the map?

Comment: Is $T$ a linear mapping?

Comment: yes, the map is like $u \mapsto (t\mapsto  \int g(x) u(x*t) dx)$.

Comment: What is known about $g$?

Comment: it behaves like $\frac{1}{1+\vert x\vert^\frac{3}{2} }$ roughly speaking